# Delete array from ionic2 local storage

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic2, storage

my data gets stored in an string

i use JSON.parse to convert data to arrays

```
this.items = JSON.parse(todos);
```

I have a results page which prints out my arrays:
Array1
Array2
Array3

I have a delete button after every array which deletes the item from the list but not from local storage. Am I doing something wrong?

list.html

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ion-item>
  <p>{{item.amount}}tk X {{item.class}} / {{item.size}}ml / {{item.proof}}%</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options>
  <button danger (click)="removePost(item)">
  <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Remove
  </button>
  </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
```

list.ts

```
removePost(item){
    let index = this.items.indexOf(item);
   if(index > -1){
      this.items.splice(index, 1); // works
      this.storage.remove(this.items[index]); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: Hw are you storing data in local storage? Local storage does not take array or objects, it only takes strings.

Comment: this.items = JSON.parse(todos);

Comment: this.items[index] this is an object right?

Comment: can you share screenshot of stored item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a JSON array in the local storage as a string and if you want to remove an object from local storage array then this will not work.

you can't remove an object because the whole value of localstorage is a string value. what you can do is after removing the value using `splice` you can set the localstorage again

```
removePost(item){
   let index = this.items.indexOf(item);
   if(index > -1){
      this.items.splice(index, 1); // works
      //this.storage.remove(this.items[index]); // doesn't work
      localStorage.setitem("name_of_the_storage",JSON.stringify(this.items))
    }
}
```